# How to draw a scatter plot, where the points with the same X-values assigned the same color?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Dear experienced friends, I am curious about how to draw a scatter plot where the points with the same X-values have the same color? Suppose we have a dataset like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list1 = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
list2 = [9,8,10,11,1,2,1,2,4,5,6,7]

plt.scatter(list1, list2)
plt.show()
```

The picture looks like this:
[image]

However, I want to draw a picture like the following one. As you can see, the points with the same x-axis value have the same color. How can I achieve this? Thank you so much in advance!

[image]

Comment: May I interest you in a seaborn [`stripplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html) or [swarmplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html#seaborn.swarmplot)?

Comment: Thank you @Mr.T, this pickage perfectly solves my question!

Comment: Thank you @G.Anderson, the answer from Tirtha is a really elegant solution. Thank you for mentioning this!  : D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the x values to the `c` parameter in the `plt.scatter` function. It will use those integral values to map the colors to the points. Same integral value would mean having the same color.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list1 = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
list2 = [9,8,10,11,1,2,1,2,4,5,6,7]

plt.scatter(list1, list2, c = list1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! May I ask is it possible to define the color on my own, through this method? Like 1 is red and 2 is green?

Comment: Yes. You can pass a list of colors into `c` as well with each value in `c` denoting a color of each point. 

To control color of each value of x, you can define a dictionary mapping each unique value in x to a color and then use that dict to create a list of colors for each point and pass that into `c`.